# Trying to use R with MySQL: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Tags: mysql, r, mysql-workbench

I am trying import a data set into a table in MySQL.  I am using MySQL 8.0.11 and version 1.1.453 of R Studio.  I am using the RMySQL package.

The line in question is:

```
dbWriteTable(ajppDb, value = EvanData, row.names = FALSE, name = "summaryfile2015", append = TRUE )
```

and I get this response:

Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

This line worked for me in version 5.7 of MySQL but not for the newer version so I'm not sure what has changed or what I am doing wrong. Does anyone know how I can import my data using R?

Answer (score 10):

The following steps should fix the `dbWritetable()` error in `R`:

1. Login `MySQL` terminal by typing "`MySQL -u user -p*`" (followed by user password if you set one).
2. Type "`SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;`" in the MySQL  terminal command.
3. Lastly, type "`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';`" into the terminal and check the command line output for the ON status.

I'm not sure why the database function fails from `MySQL` 5.6 to 8.0, however, "`local_infile`" enables user access to data loads from local sources--- this solution should work for all database interference stacks (`R`, `Python`, etc)!

Comment: For me, it said #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: It works for me, here is a way to save this option? Each time I restart mysql I need to re-type the commands