# Unable to write R dataframes as mysql tables using R

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe

When I am trying to write an R dataframe to SQL table using MySQL, it is throwing an error

Here is what I am trying:

```python
install.packages("RMySQL")
library(RMySQL)

mysql_connection = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='usr', password='pswd', dbname="my_db_name")

test_df = some_dataframe

dbWriteTable(mysql_connection, value = test_df, name = "test_table", append = TRUE )
```

And getting the following error:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :
    could not run statement: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

Comment: Question: Do you have `INSERT` rights on the `test_table` table?

Comment: You can check the issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL/issues/180) and the possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50745431/trying-to-use-r-with-mysql-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-vers?rq=1)

Comment: So not sql-server then?

Comment: check it again by adding     row.names=FALSE   in dbwrite()

Comment: Putting `SET GLOBAL local_infile = true;` helped! thanks @akrun

Comment: Do not tag indiscriminately! SQL errors and solutions are almost always dbms- specific.